# Take differences from one dataframe based on dates from another dataframe

Tags: dataframe

## Dataset A

```
Name  Date    Value  change  year NewColumn
A     2000-02   0.5  NA      2000        NA
A     2001-03   0.4  -0.200  2001         0
A     2002-02   1     1.5    2002         1
A     2003-05   0.9  -0.100  2003         0
A     2004-06   0.9   0      2004        NA
A     2006-03   0.4  -0.556  2006        NA
```

So basicalley I want to look at the column date if there is a (0/1) in my column NewColumn and then look at the dates from this year and the previous year from my dataset A and take based on that the values from the same dates but one month earlier from the dataset B and take put the difference in my new dataset.

Is there a way of coding this easily?

If not, I guess I have to do it manually by mself using excel.
Or is there a less timecomsuming way or trick I could handle this problem :)

Thank you :)

Comment: What is logic to select `year` range from `ValueDatasetB` data.frame?

Comment: Have a look at answer provided by me. I have not considered `Name` while picking up previous date. You can consider grouping on `Name` if your data got many names.

Answer (score 1):

Since, previous month is involved is joining `df_A` with `df_B` hence it would be better to prepare `df_A` by adding a column with previous date on which it can be joined with `df_B`.

Similarly, while taking data from `df_B` it involves subtraction of `ValueofInterest` from previous date hence it would be good to prepare `df_B` by adding a column storing `ValueofInterest` from previous date.

Since, date has been mentioned in `year` and `month`, hence, I preferred to use `zoo.yearmon` function to convert date.

Finally, we can join `df_A` and `df_B` to get the result as:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

# First prepaer df_A to join
df_A %>% mutate(Date = as.yearmon(Date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(DateToJoin = Date - (1/12)) %>% # The previous month for joining
  left_join(df_B %>% mutate(DateToJoin = as.yearmon(paste0(year, month),"%Y%m")) %>%
        arrange(DateToJoin) %>%
        mutate(valueToDeduct = lag(ValueofInterest)),
  by = "DateToJoin") %>%
  mutate(Difference = ifelse(is.na(NewColumn), NA , ValueofInterest-valueToDeduct)) %>%
  select(Name, Date, Value, change, year= year.x, NewColumn, Difference)

#   Name     Date Value change year NewColumn Difference
# 1    A Feb 2000   0.5     NA 2000        NA         NA
# 2    A Mar 2001   0.4 -0.200 2001         0       0.01
# 3    A Feb 2002   1.0  1.500 2002         1      -0.07
# 4    A May 2003   0.9 -0.100 2003         0       0.10
# 5    A Jun 2004   0.9  0.000 2004        NA         NA
# 6    A Mar 2006   0.4 -0.556 2006        NA         NA
```

**Data:**

```
df_A <- read.table(text = 
"Name  Date    Value  change  year NewColumn
A     2000-02   0.5  NA      2000        NA
A     2001-03   0.4  -0.200  2001         0
A     2002-02   1     1.5    2002         1
A     2003-05   0.9  -0.100  2003         0
A     2004-06   0.9   0      2004        NA
A     2006-03   0.4  -0.556  2006        NA",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df_B <- read.table(text = 
"year      month   ValueofInterest    
1999        12       0.05
2000        1        0.19          
2000        2        0.12   
2000        3        0.07
2000        4        0.11   
2000        5        0.12
2000        6        0.12
2001        1       0.05
2001        2       0.06
2001        3       0.08
2002        1       0.01
2002        2       0.07
2002        3       0.05
2003        1       0.00
2003        2       0.03
2003        3       0.15
2003        4       0.25
2003        5       0.64
2008        11       0.15
2008        12       0.03",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @bli12blu12 Thanks for the update. First part is clear to me now. For 2nd part where you have mentioend `minus ValueDatasetB(1999-09)` I'm still not able to understand? If it is just previous value then value for even `2001--01` is available. Why cannot we take that?

Comment: @bli12blu12 I have updated my answer now. Now `DateToJoin` is one month previous. Say for example for `2001-03` I should look for `2001-02` in df_B. The value is `0.06`.  Now i should look for value which should be subtracted .If I look for `year back means `2000-02`. The value is `0.12`. Hence answer should be `0.06 - 0.12` ? Is that correct?

Comment: Based on your above example :`0.06 (2001-02) - 0.19 (2000-01) = -0.13 ... 0.01 (2002-01)` this much is clear to me. Even `0.25 (2003-04)` portion is also correct. No issue.  Now,  why `0.19 (2000-01)` ?  and Similarly why  ` 0.01 (2002-01) `?  still not clear to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172311/discussion-between-mkr-and-bli12blu12).